# Convert list of number to list of strings in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is it possible to convert a list of numbers to a list of string in Google Earth Engine? I'd like to take something that looks like this

```
var lis = ee.List([27141, 20043]);
```

and convert it to something that looks like this

```
var lis = ee.List(['27141', '20043']);
```

I imagine this is really simple but I can't find a solution in GEE documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Any time you want to compute something from each element of a list you can `map` over it:

```
print(lis.map(function (number) { return ee.String(number); }));
```