# Convert list of numbers to list of strings using Python API in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am able to convert a list of numbers to a list of strings in the code editor following the answer provided [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358783/convert-list-of-number-to-list-of-strings-in-google-earth-engine) (more or less):

```
var numbers = ee.List.sequence(0, 4);
print(numbers);
var number_to_string = function(number) {
  return ee.String(ee.Number(number).int());
};
var strings = numbers.map(number_to_string);
print(strings);
```

[0,1,2,3,4]

["0","1","2","3","4"] <- strings as expected

However, when I try to run the same code (reformatted) in the Python API, the output list still contains numbers, not strings:

```
numbers = ee.List.sequence(0, 4);
print(numbers.getInfo());
def number_to_string(number):
    return ee.String(ee.Number(number).int());
strings = numbers.map(number_to_string);
print(strings.getInfo());
```

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] <- Why aren't these strings?

How can I force the conversion of a list of numbers to a list of strings in the Python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't just cast from one type to another like that, unless the types are part of the same type hierarchy (ie: Images are also Features)

Use `ee.Number(number).format("%d")`

The JavaScript API might have gotten updated to look for numbers in the String constructor.  It looks like the Python API didn't.