# Compute the Cartesian product of 2 ee.Lists

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to build the Cartesian product of 2 List in the earthengine Python API. The objective is thus to obtain a single list with all the combinations.

I coded something that runs in the JavaScript API:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/618ed5929c6fffed4b599bcfb13a29ba

```js
var l1 = ee.List(["a", "b", "c"])
var l2 = ee.List([1, 2, 3])

var product = l1.map(function(e){
  return l2.map(function(f){
    return ee.String(e).cat(ee.String(f))
  })
})
print(product.flatten())
```

But I cannot find a way to transform it to Python. I'm stucked with the following error:

```
EEException: String.cat, argument 'string2': Invalid type.
Expected type: String.
Actual type: Integer.
Actual value: 1
```

Even though I force cast everything to ee.String twice:

```py
l1 = ee.List(["a", "b", "c"]).map(lambda e: ee.String(e))
l2 = ee.List([1,  2, 3]).map(lambda e: ee.String(e))

l1.map(lambda e: l2.map(lambda f: ee.String(e).cat(ee.String(f)))).flatten().getInfo()
```

Anyone see a mistake ?

Comment: In Python it is itertools.product

Comment: thanks but the idea is here to perform everything server side, as the initial list are comming from previous computation. I'm showing it with raw list for minimal example.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/450094/181131), the python api is not compatible with the ee.String() conversion.

Comment: Ok so it will requires much more code in Python than in javascript, I'll try to find something and write it down in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Padmanabha said. Arguably, not really much more code in Python than JavaScript. An explicit conversion from String to Number, with the ability to control the formatting, might be a good idea in any case.

```
l1 = ee.List(["a", "b", "c"])
l2 = ee.List([1, 2, 3])

product = l1.map(
    lambda e: l2.map(
        lambda f: ee.String(e).cat(ee.Number(f).format('%d'))
    )
)
print(product.flatten().getInfo())
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @Daniel answer, I recently discovered the String Algorithm in the API. It allows to do the same thing without knowing the initial class of "f" or "e", making this possible:

```py
l1 = ee.List([1, "b", "c"])
l2 = ee.List(["a", 2, 3])

product = l1.map(
    lambda e: l2.map(
        lambda f: ee.Algorithms.String(e).cat(ee.Algorithms.String(f))
    )
)
print(product.flatten().getInfo())
```